# SQLServer CASE expressions - short circuit evaluation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I am trying to optimize a query that does something like this:

```
SELECT
   ...
   CASE WHEN (condition) THEN (expensive function call #1)
   ELSE (expensive function call #2) 
   END
...
```

The query plan shows that for even in cases where 100% of rows satisfy the WHEN clause, a substantial portion of the time is spent in calls to the result in the ELSE branch.

The only way I can make sense of this is to presume that SQLServer is evaluating both results, then only selecting one based on evaluation of the WHEN condition, but I can't find any definitive reference as to whether or not the results of a CASE statement are evaluated before the conditionals.  Can anyone please clarify or point me to a reference?

Comment: I can't confirm this at all, even when I try an expensive function that queries a huge table. If I set the first part of the CASE to be true 100% if the time, my query takes 5 seconds. If not, about 10 minutes .
Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that an actual or estimated plan?  Sql Server builds plans based on what it expects to do based on collected statistics, and that doesn't always jibe with what specific conditions you send it for one instance of a query run.

Comment: Oops, of course, that's it.  When the actual query is executed, the plan looks completely different.  Sorry for not thinking of that first.

Answer (score 9):

SQL is a declarative language. You express in a query the desired result and the server is free to choose whatever means to deliver those results. As such the order of evaluation of SQL epxressions is *not* determined and `OR` and `AND` evaluation short circuit does not occur.

However for `CASE` the documentation actually states that the [order of evaluation occurs in the order of declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and the evaluation stops after the first condition is met:

> - Evaluates `input_expression`, and then **in the order specified, evaluates
>     `input_expression`** = `when_expression` for
>     each `WHEN` clause.
> - Returns the `result_expression` of the first `input_expression =
>     when_expression` that evaluates to
>     `TRUE`.

That means that if you see the expression in the FALSE branch evaluated, your CASE condition is incorrect and sometimes evaluates to FALSE or UNKNOWN. Make sure that tri-values logic of SQL is taken into account (ie. you account for NULLs). Also make sure the data in the tables is the one you expect (ie. the condition *really* evaluates to FALSE 100% of the cases).

Comment: Not quite. There was a bug filed under Microsoft Connect, [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/), that demonstrated a case where the order of evaluation of the `CASE` expressions is not respected. Even the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) has been updated: "In some situations, an expression is evaluated before a CASE statement receives the results of the expression as its input."