# TSQL - Cast string to integer or return default value

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a way in T-SQL to cast an nvarchar to int and return a default value or NULL if the conversion fails?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### If you are on SQL Server 2012 (or newer):

Use the [TRY_CONVERT function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx).

### If you are on SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2:

Create a user defined function. This will avoid the issues that [Fedor Hajdu mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000421/317) with regards to currency, fractional numbers, etc:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TryConvertInt(@Value varchar(18))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Value = REPLACE(@Value, ',', '')
    IF ISNUMERIC(@Value + 'e0') = 0 RETURN NULL
    IF ( CHARINDEX('.', @Value) > 0 AND CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@Value, 1)) <> 0 ) RETURN NULL
    DECLARE @I bigint =
        CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.', @Value) > 0 THEN CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@Value, 2))
        ELSE CONVERT(bigint, @Value)
        END
    IF ABS(@I) > 2147483647 RETURN NULL
    RETURN @I
END
GO

-- Testing
DECLARE @Test TABLE(Value nvarchar(50))    -- Result
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '1234'            -- 1234
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '1,234'           -- 1234
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '1234.0'          -- 1234
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '-1234'           -- -1234
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '$1234'           -- NULL
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '1234e10'         -- NULL
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '1234 5678'       -- NULL
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '123-456'         -- NULL
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '1234.5'          -- NULL
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT '123456789000000' -- NULL
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT 'N/A'             -- NULL
SELECT Value, dbo.TryConvertInt(Value) FROM @Test
```

**Reference:** I used [this page](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423) extensively when creating my solution.

Comment: Anyone get this to work?  I created a function as suggested and find it throws conversion errors using the proposed test function. I imagine I'm missing something here...

Comment: @JosephSturtevant this is beautiful

Comment: Yes good job...

Saved me a lot of work...

I'm not on 2012 or higher due to customer...

Don't give me credit though :) I was only good at searching for the answer that worked for me...

Although I changed it from returning null to returning zero since the stupid varchar should be an int column with a default of zero :)

Answer (score 141):

Yes :). Try this:

```
DECLARE @text AS NVARCHAR(10)

SET @text = '100'
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@text) = 1 THEN CAST(@text AS INT) ELSE NULL END
-- returns 100

SET @text = 'XXX'
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@text) = 1 THEN CAST(@text AS INT) ELSE NULL END
-- returns NULL
```

[`ISNUMERIC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) has a few issues pointed by [Fedor Hajdu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243153/fedor-hajdu).

It returns true for strings like `$` (is currency), `,` or `.` (both are separators), `+` and `-`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hoped that there is something more elegant.

Comment: What about when the text value is numeric, but contains a number greater than an int column can store?

Comment: -1: Unfortunately, there are too many issues with `ISNUMERIC` for this answer to be of any use on unvalidated data (and you wouldn't need the `ISNUMERIC` check in the first place for properly-validated data). The author acknowledges the existence of these issues but does not address them.

Comment: As [Joseph Mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11552624/18192), users of SQL 2012+ should use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)/[`TRY_CAST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx), which are explicitly intended to resolve the OP's question.  This answer was written before SQL 2012 was released.

Comment: I downvote because ISNUMERIC('1,1,1,1,1') = 1 and this does never cast to int.

Comment: It's a wrong answer. Simply fails when the test is `1.9`.

Answer (score 15):

As has been mentioned, you may run into several issues if you use `ISNUMERIC`:

```
-- Incorrectly gives 0:
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('-') = 1 THEN CAST('-' AS INT) END   

-- Error (conversion failure):
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('$') = 1 THEN CAST('$' AS INT) END
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('4.4') = 1 THEN CAST('4.4' AS INT) END
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('1,300') = 1 THEN CAST('1,300' AS INT) END

-- Error (overflow):
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('9999999999') = 1 THEN CAST('9999999999' AS INT) END
```

If you want a reliable conversion, you'll need to code one yourself.

**Update**: My new recommendation would be to use an intermediary test conversion to `FLOAT` to validate the number. This approach is based on [adrianm's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256686/numeric-sort-order-for-strings-containing-same-length-integers-under-all-collati#comment37473167_24256686). The logic can be defined as an inline table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TryConvertInt (@text NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@text + '.e0') = 1 THEN 
             CASE WHEN CONVERT(FLOAT, @text) BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647 
                  THEN CONVERT(INT, @text) 
             END 
         END AS [Result]
)
```

Some tests:

```
SELECT [Conversion].[Result]
FROM ( VALUES
     ( '1234'                     )   -- 1234
   , ( '1,234'                    )   -- NULL
   , ( '1234.0'                   )   -- NULL
   , ( '-1234'                    )   -- -1234
   , ( '$1234'                    )   -- NULL
   , ( '1234e10'                  )   -- NULL
   , ( '1234 5678'                )   -- NULL
   , ( '123-456'                  )   -- NULL
   , ( '1234.5'                   )   -- NULL
   , ( '123456789000000'          )   -- NULL
   , ( 'N/A'                      )   -- NULL
   , ( '-'                        )   -- NULL
   , ( '$'                        )   -- NULL
   , ( '4.4'                      )   -- NULL
   , ( '1,300'                    )   -- NULL
   , ( '9999999999'               )   -- NULL
   , ( '00000000000000001234'     )   -- 1234
   , ( '212110090000000235698741' )   -- NULL
) AS [Source] ([Text])
OUTER APPLY TryConvertInt ([Source].[Text]) AS [Conversion]
```

Results are similar to [Joseph Sturtevant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11552624/1149773), with the following main differences:

- My logic does not tolerate occurrences of `.` or `,` in order to mimic the behaviour of native `INT` conversions. `'1,234'` and `'1234.0'` return `NULL`.
- Since it does not use local variables, my function can be defined as an inline table-valued function, allowing for better query optimization.
- Joseph's answer can lead to incorrect results due to silent truncations of the argument; `'00000000000000001234'` evaluates to `12`. Increasing the parameter length would result in errors on numbers that overflow `BIGINT`, such as [BBANs](http://www.swift.com/dsp/resources/documents/IBAN_Registry.pdf) (basic bank account numbers) like `'212110090000000235698741'`.

**Withdrawn**: The approach below is no longer recommended, as is left just for reference.

The snippet below works on non-negative integers. It checks that your string does not contain any non-digit characters, is not empty, and does not overflow (by exceeding the maximum value for the `int` type). However, it also gives `NULL` for valid integers whose length exceeds 10 characters due to leading zeros.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @text NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN
         CASE WHEN LEN(@text) BETWEEN 1 AND 9 
                OR LEN(@text) = 10 AND @text <= '2147483647' 
              THEN CAST (@text AS INT)
         END
    END
```

If you want to support any number of leading zeros, use the below. The nested `CASE` statements, albeit unwieldy, are required to promote short-circuit evaluation and reduce the likelihood of errors (arising, for example, from passing a negative length to `LEFT`).

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @text NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN
         CASE WHEN LEN(@text) BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN CAST (@text AS INT)
              WHEN LEN(@text) >= 10 THEN
              CASE WHEN LEFT(@text, LEN(@text) - 10) NOT LIKE '%[^0]%'
                    AND RIGHT(@text, 10) <= '2147483647'
                   THEN CAST (@text AS INT)
              END
         END
    END
```

If you want to support positive *and* negative integers with any number of leading zeros:

```
SELECT 
         -- Positive integers (or 0):
    CASE WHEN @text NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN
         CASE WHEN LEN(@text) BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN CAST (@text AS INT)
              WHEN LEN(@text) >= 10 THEN
              CASE WHEN LEFT(@text, LEN(@text) - 10) NOT LIKE '%[^0]%'
                    AND RIGHT(@text, 10) <= '2147483647'
                   THEN CAST (@text AS INT)
              END
         END
         -- Negative integers:
         WHEN LEFT(@text, 1) = '-' THEN
         CASE WHEN RIGHT(@text, LEN(@text) - 1) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN
              CASE WHEN LEN(@text) BETWEEN 2 AND 10 THEN CAST (@text AS INT)
                   WHEN LEN(@text) >= 11 THEN
                   CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@text, 2, LEN(@text) - 11) NOT LIKE '%[^0]%'
                         AND RIGHT(@text, 10) <= '2147483648'
                        THEN CAST (@text AS INT)
                   END
              END
         END
    END
```

Comment: To emphasise the point, short circuiting is [not guaranteed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2011/03/03/don-t-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case.aspx), even with the CASE statement.

Comment: @MichaelGreen: I'd read that article; the last update states: "The owners of this code [?] have marked this bug as fixed. From their comments, it sounds like you are supposed to be able to rely on deterministic order of expression evaluation for CASE statements." Microsoft [acknowledges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374392/sqlserver-case-expressions-short-circuit-evaluation/1374807#comment37462541_1374807) that the bug might occur for aggregates, but not for scalars.

Comment: Fair point @Douglas.  I remember reading within the last couple of months a post by one of the brand-name bloggers on CASE short circuiting mot being reliable *at compile time* even if the run-time sequencing was honoured.  I can't find that reference at this time, however.  My motivation was to warn The Community that this *may* be a problem, depending on their version/ edition/ patch level and I used that link as an examplar, is all.

Comment: @MichaelGreen: Agreed; IMHO, this is/was a serious shortcoming in SQL Server that severely limits its usability for scenarios requiring data validation.

Comment: Why don't you use BIGINT in the middle of the conversation?

Comment: @alex: You mean instead of the `RIGHT(@text, 10) <= '2147483647'` check? I assume I could have, provided that short-circuiting has been performed to protect against long numbers that would cause overflows. However, in retrospect, I would probably go with the `CONVERT(float, @text)` approach, which requires less short-circuiting. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 14):

I would rather create a function like TryParse or use T-SQL `TRY-CATCH` block to get what you wanted.

ISNUMERIC doesn't always work as intended. The code given before will fail if you do:

SET @text = '$'

$ sign can be converted to money datatype, so `ISNUMERIC()` returns true in that case. It will do the same for '-' (minus), ',' (comma) and '.' characters.

Comment: True :(. `ISNUMERIC()` returns `1` also for `,` and `.`.

Comment: ...except you cannot use TRY-CATCH inside a function (at least not in my SQL 2005 database)...[link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/132225/try-catch-fails-inside-a-function)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a useful scalar function to simulate the `TRY_CAST` function of SQL Server 2012 in SQL Server 2008.

You can see it in the next link below and we help each other to improve it. *TRY_CAST Function for SQL Server 2008* https://gist.github.com/jotapardo/800881eba8c5072eb8d99ce6eb74c8bb

> The two main differences are that you must pass 3 parameters and you
> must additionally perform an explicit CONVERT or CAST to the field.
> However, it is still very useful because it allows you to return a
> default value if CAST is not performed correctly.

```
dbo.TRY_CAST(Expression, Data_Type, ReturnValueIfErrorCast)
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN dbo.TRY_CAST('6666666166666212', 'INT', DEFAULT) IS NULL   
                        THEN 'Cast failed'  
                        ELSE 'Cast succeeded'  
                    END AS Result;
```

For now only supports the data types **INT, DATE, NUMERIC, BIT and FLOAT**

I hope you find it useful.

CODE:

```
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(1000)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TRY_CAST]'))
    BEGIN
        SET @strSQL = 'CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TRY_CAST] () RETURNS INT AS BEGIN RETURN 0 END'
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @strSQL
    END

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Description:    
                    Syntax 
                    ---------------
                    dbo.TRY_CAST(Expression, Data_Type, ReturnValueIfErrorCast)

                    +---------------------------+-----------------------+
                    |   Expression              |   VARCHAR(8000)       |
                    +---------------------------+-----------------------+
                    |   Data_Type               |   VARCHAR(8000)       |
                    +---------------------------+-----------------------+
                    |   ReturnValueIfErrorCast  |   SQL_VARIANT = NULL  |
                    +---------------------------+-----------------------+


                    Arguments
                    ---------------
                    expression
                    The value to be cast. Any valid expression.

                    Data_Type
                    The data type into which to cast expression.

                    ReturnValueIfErrorCast
                    Value returned if cast fails or is not supported. Required. Set the DEFAULT value by default.


                    Return Type
                    ----------------
                    Returns value cast to SQL_VARIANT type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null if the parameter @pReturnValueIfErrorCast is set to DEFAULT, 
                    or that the user indicates.


                    Remarks
                    ----------------
                    dbo.TRY_CAST function simulates the TRY_CAST function reserved of SQL SERVER 2012 for using in SQL SERVER 2008. 
                    dbo.TRY_CAST function takes the value passed to it and tries to convert it to the specified Data_Type. 
                    If the cast succeeds, dbo.TRY_CAST returns the value as SQL_VARIANT type; if the cast doesn´t succees, null is returned if the parameter @pReturnValueIfErrorCast is set to DEFAULT. 
                    If the Data_Type is unsupported will return @pReturnValueIfErrorCast.
                    dbo.TRY_CAST function requires user make an explicit CAST or CONVERT in ANY statements.
                    This version of dbo.TRY_CAST only supports CAST for INT, DATE, NUMERIC and BIT types.

                    
                    Examples
                    ====================================================================================================
                    
                    --A. Test TRY_CAST function returns null

                        SELECT   
                            CASE WHEN dbo.TRY_CAST('6666666166666212', 'INT', DEFAULT) IS NULL   
                            THEN 'Cast failed'  
                            ELSE 'Cast succeeded'  
                        END AS Result; 

                    GO

                    --B. Error Cast With User Value

                        SELECT   
                            dbo.TRY_CAST('2147483648', 'INT', DEFAULT) AS [Error Cast With DEFAULT],
                            dbo.TRY_CAST('2147483648', 'INT', -1) AS [Error Cast With User Value],
                            dbo.TRY_CAST('2147483648', 'INT', NULL) AS [Error Cast With User NULL Value]; 

                        GO 

                    --C. Additional CAST or CONVERT required in any assignment statement

                        DECLARE @IntegerVariable AS INT

                        SET @IntegerVariable = CAST(dbo.TRY_CAST(123, 'INT', DEFAULT) AS INT)

                        SELECT @IntegerVariable

                        GO 

                        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
                            DROP TABLE #temp

                        CREATE TABLE #temp (
                            Id INT IDENTITY
                            , FieldNumeric NUMERIC(3, 1)
                            )

                        INSERT INTO dbo.#temp (FieldNumeric)
                        SELECT CAST(dbo.TRY_CAST(12.3, 'NUMERIC(3,1)', 0) AS NUMERIC(3, 1));--Need explicit CAST on INSERT statements

                        SELECT *
                        FROM #temp

                        DROP TABLE #temp
                    
                        GO 

                    --D. Supports CAST for INT, DATE, NUMERIC and BIT types.

                        SELECT dbo.TRY_CAST(2147483648, 'INT', 0) AS [Cast failed]
                            , dbo.TRY_CAST(2147483647, 'INT', 0) AS [Cast succeeded]
                            , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(dbo.TRY_CAST(212, 'INT', 0), 'BaseType') AS [BaseType];

                        SELECT dbo.TRY_CAST('AAAA0101', 'DATE', DEFAULT) AS [Cast failed]
                            , dbo.TRY_CAST('20160101', 'DATE', DEFAULT) AS [Cast succeeded]
                            , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(dbo.TRY_CAST('2016-01-01', 'DATE', DEFAULT), 'BaseType') AS [BaseType];

                        SELECT dbo.TRY_CAST(1.23, 'NUMERIC(3,1)', DEFAULT) AS [Cast failed]
                            , dbo.TRY_CAST(12.3, 'NUMERIC(3,1)', DEFAULT) AS [Cast succeeded]
                            , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(dbo.TRY_CAST(12.3, 'NUMERIC(3,1)', DEFAULT), 'BaseType') AS [BaseType];

                        SELECT dbo.TRY_CAST('A', 'BIT', DEFAULT) AS [Cast failed]
                            , dbo.TRY_CAST(1, 'BIT', DEFAULT) AS [Cast succeeded]
                            , SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(dbo.TRY_CAST('123', 'BIT', DEFAULT), 'BaseType') AS [BaseType];

                        GO 

                    --E. B. TRY_CAST return NULL on unsupported data_types
                        
                        SELECT dbo.TRY_CAST(4, 'xml', DEFAULT) AS [unsupported];  
                        
                        GO  

                    ====================================================================================================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Responsible:    Javier Pardo 
    Date:           diciembre 29/2016
    WB tests:       Javier Pardo 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Update by:      Javier Eduardo Pardo Moreno 
    Date:           febrero 16/2017
    Id update:      JEPM20170216
    Description:    Fix  ISNUMERIC function makes it unreliable. SELECT dbo.TRY_CAST('+', 'INT', 0) will yield Msg 8114, 
                    Level 16, State 5, Line 16 Error converting data type varchar to float.
                    ISNUMERIC() function treats few more characters as numeric, like: – (minus), + (plus), $ (dollar), \ (back slash), (.)dot and (,)comma
                    Collaborator aperiooculus (http://stackoverflow.com/users/3083382/aperiooculus )

                    Fix dbo.TRY_CAST('2013/09/20', 'datetime', DEFAULT) for supporting DATETIME format

    WB tests:       Javier Pardo 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.TRY_CAST
(
    @pExpression AS VARCHAR(8000),
    @pData_Type AS VARCHAR(8000),
    @pReturnValueIfErrorCast AS SQL_VARIANT = NULL
)
RETURNS SQL_VARIANT
AS
BEGIN
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  INT 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF @pData_Type = 'INT'
    BEGIN
        IF ISNUMERIC(@pExpression) = 1 AND @pExpression NOT IN ('-','+','$','.',',','\')    --JEPM20170216
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @pExpressionINT AS FLOAT = CAST(@pExpression AS FLOAT)

            IF @pExpressionINT BETWEEN - 2147483648.0 AND 2147483647.0
            BEGIN
                RETURN CAST(@pExpressionINT as INT)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                RETURN @pReturnValueIfErrorCast
            END --FIN IF @pExpressionINT BETWEEN - 2147483648.0 AND 2147483647.0
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            RETURN @pReturnValueIfErrorCast
        END -- FIN IF ISNUMERIC(@pExpression) = 1
    END -- FIN IF @pData_Type = 'INT'
    
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  DATE    
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF @pData_Type IN ('DATE','DATETIME')
    BEGIN
        IF ISDATE(@pExpression) = 1
        BEGIN
            
            DECLARE @pExpressionDATE AS DATETIME = cast(@pExpression AS DATETIME)

            IF @pData_Type = 'DATE'
            BEGIN
                RETURN cast(@pExpressionDATE as DATE)
            END
            
            IF @pData_Type = 'DATETIME'
            BEGIN
                RETURN cast(@pExpressionDATE as DATETIME)
            END
            
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            
            DECLARE @pExpressionDATEReplaced AS VARCHAR(50) = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@pExpression,'\',''),'/',''),'-','')
            
            IF ISDATE(@pExpressionDATEReplaced) = 1
            BEGIN
                IF @pData_Type = 'DATE'
                BEGIN
                    RETURN cast(@pExpressionDATEReplaced as DATE)
                END
            
                IF @pData_Type = 'DATETIME'
                BEGIN
                    RETURN cast(@pExpressionDATEReplaced as DATETIME)
                END

            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                RETURN @pReturnValueIfErrorCast
            END
        END --FIN IF ISDATE(@pExpression) = 1
    END --FIN IF @pData_Type = 'DATE'

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  NUMERIC 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF @pData_Type LIKE 'NUMERIC%'
    BEGIN

        IF ISNUMERIC(@pExpression) = 1
        BEGIN
            
            DECLARE @TotalDigitsOfType AS INT = SUBSTRING(@pData_Type,CHARINDEX('(',@pData_Type)+1,  CHARINDEX(',',@pData_Type) - CHARINDEX('(',@pData_Type) - 1)
                , @TotalDecimalsOfType AS INT = SUBSTRING(@pData_Type,CHARINDEX(',',@pData_Type)+1,  CHARINDEX(')',@pData_Type) - CHARINDEX(',',@pData_Type) - 1)
                , @TotalDigitsOfValue AS INT 
                , @TotalDecimalsOfValue AS INT 
                , @TotalWholeDigitsOfType AS INT 
                , @TotalWholeDigitsOfValue AS INT 

            SET @pExpression = REPLACE(@pExpression, ',','.')

            SET @TotalDigitsOfValue = LEN(REPLACE(@pExpression, '.',''))
            SET @TotalDecimalsOfValue = CASE Charindex('.', @pExpression)
                                        WHEN 0
                                            THEN 0
                                        ELSE Len(Cast(Cast(Reverse(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @pExpression, 128)) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
                                        END 
            SET @TotalWholeDigitsOfType = @TotalDigitsOfType - @TotalDecimalsOfType
            SET @TotalWholeDigitsOfValue = @TotalDigitsOfValue - @TotalDecimalsOfValue

            -- The total digits can not be greater than the p part of NUMERIC (p, s)
            -- The total of decimals can not be greater than the part s of NUMERIC (p, s)
            -- The total digits of the whole part can not be greater than the subtraction between p and s
            IF (@TotalDigitsOfValue <= @TotalDigitsOfType) AND (@TotalDecimalsOfValue <= @TotalDecimalsOfType) AND (@TotalWholeDigitsOfValue <= @TotalWholeDigitsOfType)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @pExpressionNUMERIC AS FLOAT
                SET @pExpressionNUMERIC = CAST (ROUND(@pExpression, @TotalDecimalsOfValue) AS FLOAT) 
                
                RETURN @pExpressionNUMERIC --Returns type FLOAT
            END 
            else
            BEGIN
                RETURN @pReturnValueIfErrorCast
            END-- FIN IF (@TotalDigitisOfValue <= @TotalDigits) AND (@TotalDecimalsOfValue <= @TotalDecimals) 

        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            RETURN @pReturnValueIfErrorCast
        END --FIN IF ISNUMERIC(@pExpression) = 1
    END --IF @pData_Type LIKE 'NUMERIC%'
    
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  BIT 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF @pData_Type LIKE 'BIT'
    BEGIN
        IF ISNUMERIC(@pExpression) = 1
        BEGIN
            RETURN CAST(@pExpression AS BIT) 
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            RETURN @pReturnValueIfErrorCast
        END --FIN IF ISNUMERIC(@pExpression) = 1
    END --IF @pData_Type LIKE 'BIT'


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  FLOAT   
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF @pData_Type LIKE 'FLOAT'
    BEGIN
        IF ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(@pExpression, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')) = 1
        BEGIN

            RETURN CAST(@pExpression AS FLOAT) 
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            
            IF REPLACE(@pExpression, CHAR(13), '') = '' --Only white spaces are replaced, not new lines
            BEGIN
                RETURN 0
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                RETURN @pReturnValueIfErrorCast
            END --IF REPLACE(@pExpression, CHAR(13), '') = '' 
            
        END --FIN IF ISNUMERIC(@pExpression) = 1
    END --IF @pData_Type LIKE 'FLOAT'

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  Any other unsupported data type will return NULL or the value assigned by the user to @pReturnValueIfErrorCast  
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    RETURN @pReturnValueIfErrorCast
        


END
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why the negative feedback?

Comment: I do not understand how they put negative points and did not even mention the reason. That way you can not learn. Please feed back

Comment: You may want to include the implementation in your answer.

Comment: @AperioOculus thank you so much for your feedback. I updated the code! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Joseph's answer pointed out ISNUMERIC also handles scientific notation like '1.3e+3' but his answer doesn't handle this format of number.

Casting to a money or float first handles both the currency and scientific issues:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TryConvertInt]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[TryConvertInt]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TryConvertInt(@Value varchar(18))
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IntValue bigint;

    IF (ISNUMERIC(@Value) = 1)
        IF (@Value like '%e%')
            SET @IntValue = CAST(Cast(@Value as float) as bigint);
        ELSE
            SET @IntValue = CAST(CAST(@Value as money) as bigint);
    ELSE
        SET @IntValue = NULL;

    RETURN @IntValue;
END
```

The function will fail if the number is bigger than a bigint.

If you want to return a different default value, leave this function so it is generic and replace the null afterwards:

```
SELECT IsNull(dbo.TryConvertInt('nan') , 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not pretty but it is simple. Try this:

```
declare @AlpaNumber nvarchar(50) = 'ABC'
declare @MyNumber int = 0
begin Try
select @MyNumber = case when ISNUMERIC(@AlpaNumber) = 1 then cast(@AlpaNumber as int) else 0 end
End Try
Begin Catch
    -- Do nothing
End Catch 

if exists(select * from mytable where mynumber = @MyNumber)
Begin
print 'Found'
End
Else
Begin
 print 'Not Found'
End
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this issue was to create the function shown below. My requirements included that the number had to be a standard integer, not a BIGINT, and I needed to allow negative numbers and positive numbers. I have not found a circumstance where this fails.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfIsInteger]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Value nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result int = 0

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    DECLARE @MinValue nvarchar(11) = '-2147483648'
    DECLARE @MaxValue nvarchar(10) = '2147483647'

    SET @Value = ISNULL(@Value,'')

    IF LEN(@Value)=0 OR 
      ISNUMERIC(@Value)<>1 OR
      (LEFT(@Value,1)='-' AND LEN(@Value)>11) OR
      (LEFT(@Value,1)='-' AND LEN(@Value)=11 AND @Value>@MinValue) OR
      (LEFT(@Value,1)<>'-' AND LEN(@Value)>10) OR
      (LEFT(@Value,1)<>'-' AND LEN(@Value)=10 AND @Value>@MaxValue)
      GOTO FINISHED

    DECLARE @cnt int = 0
    WHILE @cnt<LEN(@Value)
    BEGIN
      SET @cnt=@cnt+1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Value,@cnt,1) NOT IN ('-','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') GOTO FINISHED
    END
    SET @Result=1

FINISHED:
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to achieve it with SQL

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRY_PARSE('not_a_number' AS INT), 0) AS 'RESULT'
```

- **TRY_PARSE** will return NULL if the conversion fails.
- **COALESCE** will return the first non-null value, you can add your desired default vaue as the second param. 0 in the example above.