# T-sql - determine if value is integer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, integer, isnumeric

I want to determine if a value is integer (like `TryParse` in .NET). Unfortunatelly `ISNUMERIC` does not fit me because I want to parse only integers and not every kind of number. Is there such thing as `ISINT` or something?

Here is some code to make things clear. If `MY_FIELD` is not int, this code would fail:

```
SELECT @MY_VAR = CAST(MY_FIELD AS INT)
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_OTHER_FIELD = 'MY_FILTER'
```

Thank you

Comment: Update: later version of SQL have the `TRY_CONVERT` function

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Or as of SQL-Server-2012 simply: TRY_CAST(my_field AS integer)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's a [blog post](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423) describing the creation of an `IsInteger` UDF.

Basically, it recommends adding `'.e0'` to the value and using `IsNumeric`. In this way, anything that already had a decimal point now has two decimal points, causing `IsNumeric` to be false, and anything already expressed in scientific notation is invalidated by the `e0`.

Comment: The function shown in the blog post is flawed in several ways. DO NOT USE IT!!! These inputs return a positive result which is clearly incorrect: SELECT /*more than 18 characters-function should accept MAX data type and test more for invalid length*/ dbo.IsInt32('99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999930'), /* 18 characters, but clearly not a valid int */ dbo.IsInt32('999999999999999999');

Comment: I've attempted to come up with a solution that should address all border cases: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24250511/1149773

Comment: Agreed that this could be an issue for really fuky, long edge cases. But works great for basic integer (i.e. numbers between 1 and 1000) testing. You can easily add a length check to the string in this case.

Comment: @Joshua - `SELECT ISNUMERIC (CHAR(11) + '.e0')` returns `0` in my case, thereby **passing** the test, not failing it

Answer (score 28):

In his article [Can I convert this string to an integer?](https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-visual-studio/can-i-convert-string-integer), Itzik Ben-Gan provides a solution in pure T-SQL and another that uses the CLR.

Which solution should you choose?

> **Is the T-SQL or CLR Solution Better?**  The advantage of using the T-SQL
> solution is that you don’t need to go outside the domain of T-SQL
> programming. However, the CLR solution has two important advantages:
> It's simpler and faster. When I tested both solutions against a table
> that had 1,000,000 rows, the CLR solution took two seconds, rather
> than seven seconds (for the T-SQL solution), to run on my laptop. So
> the next time you need to check whether a given string can be
> converted to an integer, you can include the T-SQL or CLR solution
> that I provided in this article.

If you only want to maintain T-SQL, then use the pure T-SQL solution. If performance is more important than convenience, then use the CLR solution.

The pure T-SQL Solution is tricky. It combines the built-in ISNUMERIC function with pattern-matching and casting to check if the string represents an int.

```
SELECT keycol, string, ISNUMERIC(string) AS is_numeric,
  CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(string) = 0     THEN 0
    WHEN string LIKE '%[^-+ 0-9]%' THEN 0
    WHEN CAST(string AS NUMERIC(38, 0))
      NOT BETWEEN -2147483648. AND 2147483647. THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS is_int
FROM dbo.T1;
```

The T-SQL part of the CLR solution is simpler. You call the fn_IsInt function just like you would call ISNUMERIC.

```
SELECT keycol, string, ISNUMERIC(string) AS is_numeric,
  dbo.fn_IsInt(string) AS is_int
FROM dbo.T1;
```

The C# part is simply a wrapper for the .NET's parsing function Int32.TryParse. This works because the SQL Server int and the .NET Int32 are both 32-bit signed integers.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlBoolean fn_IsInt(SqlString s)
    {
        if (s.IsNull)
            return SqlBoolean.False;
        else
        {
            Int32 i = 0;
            return Int32.TryParse(s.Value, out i);
        }
    }
};
```

Please read Itzik's article for a full explanation of these code samples.

Comment: The pure T-SQL function fails with a "data truncation" error if the input is longer than 38 characters. See my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19426/5) where I compare this solution and the currently accepted answer.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC(',')` returns 1 (true) which IMO is false!

Answer (score 23):

With sqlserver 2005 and later you can use regex-like character classes with LIKE operator. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

To check if a string is a non-negative integer (it is a sequence of decimal digits) you can test that it doesn't contain other characters.

```
SELECT numstr
  FROM table
 WHERE numstr NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Note1: This will return empty strings too.

Note2: Using `LIKE '%[0-9]%'` will return any string that contains at least a digit.

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/372fd/3/0)

Comment: ...assuming you only want to return positive integers.

Comment: @DatumPoint You're right, it works for positive integers or 0.

Answer (score 10):

```
WHERE IsNumeric(MY_FIELD) = 1 AND CAST(MY_FIELD as VARCHAR(5)) NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

That is probably the simplest solution.  Unless your `MY_FIELD` contains .00 or something of that sort.  In which case, cast it to a float to remove any trailing .00s

Comment: This does not work for comma-delimited values. For example, ISNUMERIC('123,456,789') returns 1

Answer (score 6):

Necromancing.
As of SQL-Server 2012+, you can use TRY_CAST, which returns NULL if the cast wasn't successful.

Example:

```
DECLARE @foo varchar(200)
SET @foo = '0123' 
-- SET @foo = '-0123' 
-- SET @foo = '+0123' 
-- SET @foo = '+-0123' 
-- SET @foo = '+-0123' 
-- SET @foo = '.123' 
-- SET @foo = '1.23' 
-- SET @foo = '.' 
-- SET @foo = '..' 
-- SET @foo = '0123e10' 

SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(@foo AS integer) IS NULL AND @foo IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isInteger
```

This is the only really reliable way.

Should you need support for SQL-Server 2008, then fall back to Sam DeHaan's answer:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@foo + '.e0') = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isInteger
```

SQL-Server < 2012 (aka 2008R2) will reach end of (extended) support by 2019-07-09.
At this time, which is very soon, support for < 2012 can be dropped. 
I wouldn't use any of the other hacks at this point in time anymore.
Just tell your frugal customers to update - it's been over 10 years since 2008.

Answer (score 4):

Use TRY_CONVERT which is an SQL alternative to TryParse in .NET. IsNumeric() isn’t aware that empty strings are counted as (integer)zero, and that some perfectly valid money symbols, by themselves, are not converted to (money)zero. [reference](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/)

```
SELECT @MY_VAR = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(INT,MY_FIELD) IS NOT NULL THEN MY_FIELD
                 ELSE 0
                 END
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_OTHER_FIELD = 'MY_FILTER'
```

Comment: Very nice anwer. I don't know why this powerful answer didn't get up-votes, but just one. Mine is just second.

Answer (score 3):

> See whether the below query will help

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CHARINDEX('.',MY_FIELD) = 0 AND CHARINDEX(',',MY_FIELD) = 0       
AND ISNUMERIC(MY_FIELD) = 1 AND CONVERT(FLOAT,MY_FIELD) / 2147483647 <= 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This work around with IsNumeric function will work:

`select * from A where ISNUMERIC(x) =1 and X not like '%.%'`

or Use

`select * from A where x **not like** '%[^0-9]%'`

Answer (score 3):

The following is correct for a `WHERE` clause; to make a function wrap it in `CASE WHEN`.

```
 ISNUMERIC(table.field) > 0 AND PATINDEX('%[^0123456789]%', table.field) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @i numeric(28,5) = 12.0001


if (@i/cast(@i as int) > 1)
begin
    select 'this is not int'
end
else
begin
    select 'this is int'
end
```

Comment: This is the solution I used. It has the added benefit of being the textbook definition of what an integer is. I would mark this one as an answer to the OP question.

Answer (score 2):

As of SQL Server 2012, the `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` functions were implemented. Thise are vast improvements over the `ISNUMERIC` solution, which can (and does) give false positives (or negatives). For example if you run the below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int,V.S)
FROM (VALUES('1'),
            ('900'),
            ('hello'),
            ('12b'),
            ('1.1'),
            ('')) V(S)
WHERE ISNUMERIC(V.S) = 1;
```

Using `TRY_CONVERT` (or `TRY_CAST`) avoids that:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(int,V.S),
       V.S,
       ISNUMERIC(V.S)
FROM (VALUES('1'),
            ('900'),
            ('hello'),
            ('12b'),
            ('1.1'),
            ('')) V(S)
--WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int,V.S) IS NOT NULL; --To filter to only convertable values
```

Notice that `'1.1'` returned `NULL`, which cause the error before (as a string represtation of a decimal cannot be converted to an `int`) but also that `''` returned `0`, even though `ISNUMERIC` states the value "can't be converted".

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is something wrong with your database design. I think it is a really bad idea to mix varchar and numbers in one column? What is the reason for that?

Of course you can check if there are any chars other than [0-9], but imagine you have a 1m rows in table and your are checking every row. I think it won't work well.

Anyway if you really want to do it I suggest doing it on the client side.

Comment: Sometimes you get what you are given to work with, and what you are given to work with may be a poor database design.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling doing it this way is the work of satan, but as an alternative:

How about a TRY - CATCH?

```
DECLARE @Converted as INT
DECLARE @IsNumeric BIT

BEGIN TRY
    SET @Converted = cast(@ValueToCheck as int)
    SET @IsNumeric=1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @IsNumeric=0
END CATCH

select IIF(@IsNumeric=1,'Integer','Not integer') as IsInteger
```

This works, though only in SQL Server 2008 and up.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this script and got the answer

```
ISNUMERIC(Replace(Replace([enter_your_number],'+','A'),'-','A') + '.0e0')
```

for example for up question this is answer:

```
SELECT @MY_VAR = CAST(MY_FIELD AS INT)
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_OTHER_FIELD = 'MY_FILTER' and ISNUMERIC(Replace(Replace(MY_FIELD,'+','A'),'-','A') + '.0e0') = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like:

```
CASE
WHEN ROUND(MY_FIELD,0)=MY_FIELD THEN CAST(MY_FIELD AS INT)
ELSE MY_FIELD
END
as MY_FIELD2
```

Comment: because `SELECT ROUND('abc',0)` throws an exception.

Comment: I don't believe the question implies a need to determine if a string is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't get to design the database, you just have to work with what you are given. In my case it's a database located on a computer that I only have read access to which has been around since 2008.

I need to select from a column in a poorly designed database which is a `varchar` with numbers 1-100 but sometimes a random string. I used the following to get around it (although I wish I could have re designed the entire database).

```
SELECT A from TABLE where isnumeric(A)=1
```

Comment: While I encounter troubly databases quite often I'd like to say that poorly designed databases are not always the fault of developers. Budget is your true enemy in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Pro in SQL but what about checking if it is devideable by 1 ?
For me it does the job.

```
SELECT *
FROM table    
WHERE fieldname % 1 = 0
```

Comment: For me this results in an error when `fieldname` contains a non-numeric string like 'Test'.

Answer (score 0):

Use PATINDEX

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(10)='102030.40'
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',RTRIM(LTRIM(@input))) AS IsNumber
```

reference 
http://www.intellectsql.com/post-how-to-check-if-the-input-is-numeric/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question. I finally used

```
where ATTRIBUTE != round(ATTRIBUTE)
```

and it worked for me

Comment: Hi, the question is over 8 years old and has already an accepted answer. This should be a comment rather than an answer. I don't see how rounding would solve the issue addressed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE IsNumeric(value + 'e0') = 1 AND CONVERT(FLOAT, value) BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is quite old, but my solution isn't here, i thought to add another possible way to do this:

```
  --This query only returns values with decimals
  SELECT ActualCost
  FROM TransactionHistory
  where  cast(ActualCost as int) != ActualCost

  --This query only returns values without decimals
  SELECT ActualCost
  FROM TransactionHistory
  where  cast(ActualCost as int) = ActualCost
```

The easy part here is checking if the selected value is the same when cast as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

we can check if its a non integer by

> ```
> SELECT number2  
>   FROM table
>  WHERE number2  LIKE '%[^0-9]%' and (( right(number2 ,len(number2)-1)  LIKE '%[^0-9]%'  and  lefT(number2 ,1) <> '-') or ( right(number2 ,len(number2)-1)  LIKE '%[^0-9]%'  and  lefT(number2 ,1) in ( '-','+') )  )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @zip_code NCHAR(10)

SET @zip_code = '1239'

IF TRY_PARSE( @zip_code AS INT) / TRY_PARSE( @zip_code AS INT) = 1 PRINT 'integer' 
ELSE PRINT 'not integer'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

To find out if a field is an integer I would do this:

```
SELECT IIF(RIGHT(MY_FIELD/1, 2)='00', 'DECIMAL', 'INTEGER')
```

Answer (score -1):

This works fine in SQL Server

SELECT (SELECT ISNUMERIC(2) WHERE ISNUMERIC(2)=1 AND  2 NOT LIKE '%.%')

Comment: This has already been covered in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46175121/2605758).

Answer (score -1):

`Case

   When (LNSEQNBR / 16384)%1 = 0 then 1
   else 0
end`

Comment: Hi Grady, what is LNSEQNBR in T-SQL? Ans whats with the number 16384?