# Using IN with convert in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to use the `IN` clause, but with the `convert` function.
Basically, I have a table (`A`) with the column of type `int`.
But in the other table (`B`) I Have values which are of type `varchar`.
Essentially, what I am looking for something like this

```
select *
from B
where myB_Column IN (select myA_Columng from A)
```

However, I am not sure if the `int` from table `A`, would map / convert / evaluate properly for the `varchar` in `B`.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html. You'll need to do a conversion in your subquery.

Comment: You will get an implicit cast from varchar to int that will fail if the string column has any data that does not convert. Why are you storing ints as strings?

Comment: @Dima seeing in your previous question, are all question were not answered even once?

Comment: @njk . . . Or a conversion on myB_column outside the subquery.

Comment: That means you should accept those answers that best addresses your needs. This will encourage the community members to help you more to sort out your problems.

Comment: @dima-r is there a good reason you did not accept any answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CASE statement in where clause like this and CAST only if its Integer.
else 0 or NULL depending on your requirements.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   B 
WHERE  CASE ISNUMERIC(myB_Column) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(myB_Column AS INT) ELSE 0 END
 IN (SELECT myA_Columng FROM A)
```

ISNUMERIC will be 1 (true) for Decimal values as-well so ideally you should implement your own **IsInteger** UDF .To do that look at this question

[T-sql - determine if value is integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517777/t-sql-determine-if-value-is-integer)

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1

```
Select * from B where myB_Column IN 
(
      Select Cast(myA_Columng As Int) from A Where ISNUMERIC(myA_Columng) = 1
)
```

### Option #2

```
Select B.* from B 
Inner Join
(
    Select Cast(myA_Columng As Int) As myA_Columng from A 
    Where ISNUMERIC(myA_Columng) = 1
) T
On T.myA_Columng = B.myB_Column
```

### Option #3

```
Select B.* from B 
Left Join
(
    Select Cast(myA_Columng As Int) As myA_Columng from A 
    Where ISNUMERIC(myA_Columng) = 1
) T
On T.myA_Columng = B.myB_Column
```

**I will opt third one. Reason is below mentioned.**

### Disadvantages of IN Predicate

Suppose I have two list objects.

```
List 1      List 2
  1           12
  2            7
  3            8
  4           98
  5            9
  6           10
  7            6
```

**Using Contains, it will search for each List-1 item in List-2 that means iteration will happen 49 times !!!**

Comment: It's the `B` table that's got the `varchar` column and `A` with the `int` one.

Comment: @AndrityM - Sorry, I reversed the tables. But I hope the logic should be clear to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `exists` caluse,

```
select *
from B
where EXISTS (select 1 from A WHERE CAST(myA_Column AS VARCHAR) = myB_Column)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query :

```
select B.*
from  B
inner join (Select distinct MyA_Columng from A) AS X ON B.MyB_Column = CAST(x.MyA_Columng as NVARCHAR(50))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it by using `CAST()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   B 
WHERE  CAST(myB_Column AS INT(11)) IN (
                                       SELECT myA_Columng
                                       FROM A
                                      )
```

Comment: looking at the question myB_Column is the column that needs casting.

Comment: Thanks.  I did this, but the other way around
SELECT * 
FROM   B 
WHERE  CAST(myB_Column,AS INT(11)) IN (SELECT myA_Column
                      FROM A)

and it worked