# Best way to validate a number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I know the newer versions have a try parse method similar to c# but unfortunately I'm on 2005. I know the knock on the built-in function to validate numbers is that it technically doesn't and many recommend creating one.

Is it acceptable and efficient to just use a try catch block with the catch block being considered false? ie

```
TRY
CONVERT(decimal(19,2),@value)
END TRY
GO
BEGIN CATCH
--false. Log error (or whatever you want to do)
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: You can use ISNUMERIC function

Comment: ISNUMERIC is the buil-int function I referenced that isn't a true way to verify a string is numeric and most places I've worked always had to create their own version

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking for numeric validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428131/checking-for-numeric-validation)

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually you can use negative like expression to check whether the value is is numeric or not. it is something like this

```
select case when numberAsString not like '%[^0-9]%' then 'true' else 'false' end from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

**ISNUMERIC** returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0. Valid numeric data types include the following:

```
int
numeric
bigint
money
smallint
smallmoney
tinyint
float
decimal
real
```

ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols, see [money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms179882.aspx)

```
select ISNUMERIC(@Value)
select case when ISNUMERIC(@Value) == 1 then 'Numeric' else 'Non Numeric' end
```

You can convert string value to numeric or any other types.

```
TRY
    select CONVERT(numeric(18,2),@value)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
--false. Log error (or whatever you want to do)
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: Yes, `ISNUMERIC` answers the question that *nobody* has ever wanted to ask "can I convert this string to *any* of the numeric data types, I don't care which ones?"

Answer (score 0):

SQL2012:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (NumAsString VARCHAR(22))
INSERT  @Test VALUES ('12.3'), ('123.45'), ('123.'), ('123'), ('.4'), ('.45'), ('.'), (''), (null)

SELECT  t.NumAsString, 
  CASE 
    WHEN TRY_PARSE(t.NumAsString AS DECIMAL(19,2)) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS [is numeric(19,2)]
FROM    @Test t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2160)

Comment: The question specifically states that the OP is on SQL Server 2005.