# How to find exact row where SQL query fail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have 2 tables `old` and `new` and about 500k rows.

I need to convert data from `old` to `new`. Some columns were changed. For example in `old` table many columns are of type `varchar` and in `new` table `int`.

I'm executing query like this:

```
INSERT INTO new (xxx)
    SELECT FROM old (yyy)
```

And get following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Tammi ' to data type int.

This error shows, that in `old` table are some rows with wrong data in columns. (Human factor).

But how can I find these wrong rows? Is it possible?

How can I find in what column wrong data is present?

Comment: check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10517777/1080354

Comment: Your query shows only a *single* column used, `yyy`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pain.  But, to find values that cannot be converted to ints, try this:

```
select yyyy
from old
where yyyy like '%[^0-9]%';
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `try_convert()`:

```
select yyyy
from old
where try_convert(int, yyyy) is null;
```

Comment: I have more than 50 columns in `old` table.:)

Comment: @Lari13 so what? :) do that 50 times.

Comment: @Lari13 if you have 50 columns with *text* data you shouldn't be trying to force them into integer columns. You should analyze your data first and decide whether the data is in error or you simply shouldn't be using integer columns. SSIS has tasks that can analyze sources without any effort from your part

Comment: That was the question, how to find `wrong rows` fast. I've found answer here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/

Comment: @Lari13 actually, that's the same as Gordon's first query. Your original question only mentioned a *single* column

Answer (score 0):

Could you execute the code that this `T-SQL` statement generates (just change the table name):

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME = 'DataSource'

SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' +
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT 'OR ISNUMERIC([' + name + '] + ''.e0'') = 0 '
        FROM sys.columns
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,3
    ,''
);
```

For, example, if we have the following table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DataSource') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE DataSource;
END; 
GO

CREATE TABLE DataSource  
(
    A VARCHAR(12)
   ,B VARCHAR(12)
   ,C VARCHAR(12)
);

GO

INSERT DataSource ([A], [B], [C])
VALUES ('1', '2', '3')
      ,('0.5', '4', '2')
      ,('1', '2', 'A');

GO
```

The script will generate this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM DataSource WHERE ISNUMERIC([A] + '.e0') = 0 OR ISNUMERIC([B] + '.e0') = 0 OR ISNUMERIC([C] + '.e0') = 0
```

returning two of the rows (because `A` and `0.5` cannot be converted to `int`):

[image]