# T-SQL Dealing with Rogue data when Converting to Datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, outofrangeexception

I'm pulling data out of a CRM into a reporting system. 
Unfortunately the developers of CRM thought it a good idea to store a `date` as a `string`, and then not put validation on the field.

I'm trying to do this `MAX(Convert(datetime,Action.DateOfAction, 102))`; however, because there is some invalid data I am getting an out of range error.

How do I work around this? I can't just fix the data as clearly we are still going to get some invalid data entered by users occasionally, and I can't fix the application because I don't have the source.

Thanks

Ian

Comment: This may hold your answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000045/tsql-cast-string-to-integer-or-return-default-value

Comment: Have you read anything about artificial intelligence?  Maybe it can figure out what the user intended... but I cannot.  Datetimes can cast to floats.  If you cannot cast it to a float, it's not a valid datetime.  Can you help us understand what you'd like to happen?  If it cannot cast, null?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to determine what to do with your bad data, but it looks like you want `IF ISDATE`

```
IF ISDATE(Action.DateOfAction) //do whatever
ELSE //Handle Bad data
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements but there are alternatives.
Allen give a good one, another can be using try catch.

By a general way I can create a view or computed column and use isdate to give me the date or return a null if it cannot be "parsed".

Warning, setting date format/language/localization ill change isdate evaluation.