# Have strange DB developed which has no keys and allows entry of numbers into varchar which also allows nulls

Tags: t-sql, casting, varchar

How can I ensure that TSQL will not bark at me with
these values returned:

'1.00000000'
or
NULL
or
''
or 
'some value'

When i convert to an int

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you may use the `TRY_CONVERT` function, e.g.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 123 AS intVal UNION ALL
    SELECT '123' UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL
)

SELECT
    intVal,
    CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, intVal) IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS can_parse
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The `TRY_CONVERT` function will return `NULL` in this case if it can't convert the input to an integer.  So, this is a safe way to probe your data before trying a formal cast or conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the answer I found that worked for me...
[TSQL - Cast string to integer or return default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000045/tsql-cast-string-to-integer-or-return-default-value/11552624#11552624)
I'm not on 2012 or higher due to customer...

Don't give me credit though :) I was only good at searching for the answer that worked for me...

Although I changed it from returning null to returning zero since the stupid varchar should be an int column with a default of zero :)

Here's one that works for any value that is truly a VARCHAR and not an int
since VARCHAR is really a variable length string data type

```
WITH tmpTable AS (
SELECT '123' as intVal UNION ALL
SELECT 'dog' UNION ALL
SELECT '345' UNION ALL
SELECT 'cat' UNION ALL
SELECT '987' UNION ALL
SELECT '4f7g7' UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
```

)

```
SELECT
intVal
,case when intVal not like '%[^0-9]%' then 'yes' else 'no' end FROM tmpTable;
```

credit given to Tim Biegeleisen for his answer above.... 
All though when characters are found with his solution it will 
still error out... hence the changes

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=98d4cef944d005fbe7fd080ed3d445a8)