# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

My query is like this:

```
where (:startDate is null or :endDate is null or DDATE between :startDate AND :endDate)
AND (:startDate is null or (:endDate is not null or DDATE between :startDate AND :date))
```

I get `startDate` and `endDate` from ajax date picker. `date` is the system date, which I am getting like this:

```
Date utiDate = new Date();
```

When I execute my query, I get the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY
```

Comment: Just to be sure the problem is there: change `:date` with `:enddate`. You won't have the correct result, but you'll be sure that the problem is in the type of `:date` and not in `:startdate` or `:enddate`. You should obtain a result or a different exception.

Comment: A guess would be the nested condition (:endDate is not null or VDDATE between :startDate AND :date). Have you tried running it without the nested brackets?

Comment: @eternay I replaced it with startdate as u suggested but i still get the same error.

Comment: @howiewylie: I removed the nested condition and still the same error occurs.

Comment: So, the problem is not generated by `:date`, since replacing it by another value didn't remove the exception. Can you please give the database you're using (Oracle, MySql, SQLServer...) and the type of DDDATE and VDDATE fields?

Comment: Sorry, the error code (ORA-xxx) shows that it's an Oracle database. Just forget my previous comment.

Comment: The query works fine with just `(:startDate is null or :endDate is null or DDATE between :startDate AND :endDate)`  but when i add the condition `(:startDate is null or (:endDate is not null or DDATE between :startDate AND :date)`  the error occurs

Comment: This problem occurs only when my endDate is null.                         I tried the TO_DATE(:startDate,'yyyymmdd') suggested by @eternay but it throws me an error `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
`                                                                    so i converted startDate and endDate to string before assigning and it gives me an error                                                    `ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0`   I dont know what this is for

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trying to find the correct answer, I found an interesting post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063995/behavior-of-sql-or-and-and-operator).

If `:endDate` is null, you can't be sure the condition `DDATE between :startDate AND :endDate` won't be evaluated. And if it's evaluated, Oracle will try to convert a null value to a date, so it'll give you an error.

Try to test the query removing the `DDATE between :startDate AND :endDate` part: you shouldn't have the error anymore. Then you'll have to modify your query to be sure the `between` operator won't be evaluated if `:enddate` is null. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated), they recommend using `CASE` statements inside the `WHERE` clause. Maybe it can solve your problem.

About short-circuit evaluation and Oracle database, I found [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900631/does-oracle-use-short-circuit-evaluation) that can help you understand the problem.

Comment: Ur answer helped me i did it using stringbuilder like this                       
     ` if(startDate!=null)
       if(endDate!=null)
       temp.append("AND (TRS_RCVDDATE between :startDate AND :endDate) ");
      if(startDate!=null)
       if(endDate==null)
       temp.append("AND (TRS_RCVDDATE between:startDate AND :date) ");`

Answer (score 2):

Properties :startDate and :endDate in your bean are not of type java.util.Date, but something else that Hibernate can't convert to SQL-DATE automatically and is sending BINARY as default.

You need to implement [javax.persistence.AttributeConverter< X, Y >](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html)

There is some [tutorial](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/) on that.

Hint: if you place that converter in some jar included in your war app, you must explicitly list it in persistemce.xml, otherwise your converter will not be found:

```
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/mydb</jta-data-source>

        <!-- register converter -->
        <class>com.example.persistence.LocalDateTimeConverter</class>
        ...
```