# @Query with case statement : Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot app and as database Im using Oracle and, I want to filter the returning result by start date and end date, I used this query

```
@Query(
        value = "select * from student s inner join usuario u on s.email=u.email where u.usuario = ?#{principal.username} and ((trunc(s.date_creation) >= ?1 AND ?2 is null) or (trunc(s.date_creation) >= ?1 AND trunc(s.date_creation) <= ?2))",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    Page<Student> findByCurrentStudentByPeriod(LocalDate startDate, Optional<LocalDate> endDate, Pageable pageable);
```

but I got this error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY
```

this answer gives the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/16592812/14994239, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320806/14994239 suggests to use Case statement

I made it with Case statement like below but is not working

```
select * from student s inner join usuario u on s.email=u.email where u.usuario = ?#{principal.username} and (Case when ?2 is null then trunc(s.date_creation) >= ?1 else (trunc(s.date_creation) >= ?1 AND trunc(s.date_creation) <= ?2) end)
```

Here is my controller

```
@GetMapping("/studentCourant/dateCreation")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getAllStudentByPeriod(
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate startDate,
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Optional<LocalDate> endDate,
        @org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable
    ) {
   
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of StudentCourant by dateCreation");
        Page<Student> page = studentRepository.findByCurrentStudentByPeriod(
            startDate,
            endDate,
            pageable
        );
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

Any help would appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Show the code how are you calling the query, it seems that the parameter 1 (date) has a wrong type.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber okey, I added it above (controller)

Comment: please show all the Table DDLs

Comment: if you are using hibernate or similar turn on sql tracing and show the SQL that is actually executed.