# SQL - Prioritizing WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a situation in which a rather simple looking select statement takes few minutes to complete; this statement looks like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyView
 WHERE MyFunction(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) = 1
   AND Col_8 = 20
;
```

Now, the time is distributed (roughly) as 1/3 for the select and 2/3 for the invocation of `MyFunction` (measured by simply commenting the function call and comparing with the full select time).

Now, the second condition alone (i.e. `Col_8 = 20`) already reduces the number of records.

I tried running the same query twice, having the function call first and having it second, and both returned the same values (of course) but also took the same time.

I was wondering how to prevent the invocation of the function if the first condition already failed, and thought of two alternatives:

1. Set the first condition as `Col_8 = 20` and the second as a CASE of the first (i.e. if the first failed return FALSE otherwise invoke the function),
2. Build the query as a select within a select.

Best (for may reasons!) would be to have something like in some programming languages (Ada is the first that popped) where you can write things like:

```
<condition 1> AND THEN <condition 2>...
```

Comment: If you add an index on `col_8` the execution time should reduce to only the time the function needs

Comment: It looks like you're using a scalar-valued function. Are you aware SVFs are the devil, and the use of inline table-valued functions (TVFs) is a better idea in almost all cases?

Comment: Thanks @juergend. As for the name, it is of course for the question. The real database has more meaningful names. As fod the index, assume that the **view** is a given and cannot be changed.

Comment: The `CASE` method is the only way that is (mostly) guaranteed. "Build the query as a select within a select." isn't guaranteed as SQL Server can push predicates around.

Comment: Show us the view definition, and its tables and indexes.

Comment: If you use a function in where, the db engine will not use the indexes on columns 1-4. Consider dropping the function.

Comment: @jannagy02, dropping the function is neither an option nor part of the question's purpose.

Comment: @FDavidov, Please check the post from Sefe below, I ment exactly that by dropping. Of course, because MyFunction is not posted in the question, only you could decide if you can drop it or not from the query.

Comment: No problem @jannagy02. Unfortunately, the person that coded the view and the function is no longer working for the company, otherwise I would be dropping him(!) (I'm sure that if you would see the code of the function, you would be eager to give me a hand with this). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scalar function is the problem!

These operations force the optimizer to perform [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) operations i.e. a table scan.

More information: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/135321/

So to fix, you need to bin the scalar function! You have a couple of options...

1. Move the function logic inline
2. Re-write the scalar function to be a table-valued function

I'll run through these options using the following code as a [very] basic approximation of your scalar function, in order to illustrate the point:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction (
   @a int
 , @b int
 , @c int
 , @d int
)
  RETURNS bit
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value bit = 0;
    IF @a + @b + @c + @c > 5
      BEGIN
        SET @return_value = 1;
      END
    ;

    RETURN @return_value
  END
;
```

---

Move the logic inline:

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyView
WHERE  Col_8 = 20
AND    Col_1 + Col_2 + Col_3 + Col_4 > 5
;
```

---

Make a TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyNewFunction (
   @a int
 , @b int
 , @c int
 , @d int
)
  RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
SELECT Cast(CASE WHEN @a + @b + @c + @c > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS return_value
;
```

Then call it

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyView
 CROSS
 APPLY dbo.MyNewFunction(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) AS x
WHERE  MyView.Col_8 = 20
AND    x.return_value = 1
;
```

Comment: this is the select within a select that I mentioned, and also mentioned that the function is consuming 2/3 of the time.

Comment: this doesn't force order of execution. See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors

Comment: A huge NO. sub-queries do not guarantee order of execution.

Comment: Oooh - I did not know that about the sub-query - thank you chaps - every day is a school day!

Comment: @FDavidov answer updated to provide alternative approaches, which should alleviate the performance problems of the scalar UDF you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestions. I'm up-voting it for being the most comprehensive of all the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Functions in a `WHERE` statement are bad, since they have to be executed for each row. Also, indexing is not possible in this case. If [your function is deterministic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) and the columns it uses come from one table you can use it in the base table of your view to create a persisted computed column. That column can be used in your `WHERE` statement and it can also be indexed for better performance:

```
ALTER TABLE MyBaseTable
ADD ComputedCol AS MyFunction(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) PERSISTED
```

You can then select using the computed column:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyView
WHERE ComputedCol = 1 AND Col_8 = 20
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was not focused on changing things in the existing implementation, but on the ability to prioritize / set execution order to the conditions in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Actually by using a sub select your are not guaranteeing anything , the order of the execution is unknown .

I have a different suggestion, not sure if it will improve performance. Use a derived table:

```
SELECT *
INTO TMP_FOR_SELECT
FROM MyView
WHERE Col_8 = 20;

SELECT * FROM TMP_FOR_SELECT 
WHERE  MyFunction(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) = 1;
```

Other then that, I can only suggest an index on `Col_8` which will help the optimizer find the result quicker .

Comment: This doesn't guarantee things any more than a derived table or CTE would (i.e. not at all)

Comment: +1, that's the only reliable way to force an order on filters. However, you might have accidentally used ORACLE syntax instead of SQL Server. SQL Server is `SELECT ...  INTO TMP_FOR_SELECT FROM ...`. Also, I'd use a real temporary table, i.e. `#tmp_for_select`.

Comment: @MartinSmith That actually does guarantee only records with `Col_8 = 20` will be sent to the function . Unless I am missing something?

Comment: @Heinzi, apparently, that's not the only way

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: CASE WHEN does not *always* short-circuit, see the comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1374807/87698).

Comment: @sagi - views are inlined into the query and predicates can be pushed into the view and rearranged.

Comment: Sorry I read that as a `CREATE VIEW AS query` - the invalid `CREATE TABLE AS query` syntax threw me.

Comment: I didn't understood what you were talking about :P I forgot SQL-Server has different syntax for it .

Comment: @Heinzi - Applys only to aggregate functions

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MyView
WHERE   case 
            when Col_8 = 20 
            then case 
                    when MyFunction(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) = 1 
                    then 1 
                 end 
        end = 1
;
```

And if you have an index on Col_8

```
SELECT      *

FROM        MyView

WHERE       Col_8 = 20 

        and case 
                when Col_8 = 20 
                then case 
                        when MyFunction(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) = 1 
                        then 1 
                     end 
            end = 1
;
```

Comment: Hey Dudu. Yes, that one of the options I presented in my question, but was hoping there was something more **ELLEGANT**. Thanks.